# Raspberry Pi streaming video - stream is accessible locally, but port forwarding is not working

Tags: port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

**What I'm trying to do:**

Stream video from a Raspberry Pi connected to a mifi router, and access the stream from a different network using port forwarding.

**What I've done:**

I'm running **motion** on a Raspberry Pi 3B+. I have the streaming settings in motion set as follows:

deamon on
  stream port 8081
  stream_localhost off
  webcontrol_port 8082
  webcontrol_localhost off

I'm able to connect to the camera stream on my local network: on the Pi, I type `<localhost>:port` and I get the stream. When I connect my phone to the local network I type the local IP address of my Pi and the same port and I have access to the stream once again. The problem starts when I want to access the stream remotely.

**What I have:**

I have the Pi connected to a mifi router. It's just like a normal router except it uses LTE (the IBR900-600M). I go to security/zone firewall/Port forward and proxy. I added a port forwarding rule as follows:

- Name: testPI
- Enabled
- Internet Port(s) 8080 > 8089 (The router allows me to select a range of ports so I selected a whole bunch since security is not my first concern.)
- Local computer 192.168.0.75 (local IP of my Raspberry Pi, the router does add a prompt confirming it is indeed the raspi)
- Local Port(s) 8081 > 8090
- Protocols TCP & UDP

**I have rebooted my router and Pi.**

**I'm using NOIP2 on the Pi to get a fixed hostname.**

No matter if I use the global IP of the Pi with the port, or the hostname from NOIP followed by the port, or the associated IP address followed by the port, the connection times out. I'm trying to access it from my home network which is different from the mifi router the Pi is connected to. All port forwarding testers have said the port is closed. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a public IP address on your router?